# Showing that $f(x)$ is well-defined and continuous on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

Let $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ and

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x-k)^2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x+k)^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}$$

I need to show that $f(x)$ is well-defined and continuous on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

The hint our professor gave us was to look at a $x \in [-K, K]$, $K \in \mathbb{N}$, and write $f(x)$ as

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x-k)^2}+\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x+k)^2}+\sum_{k=-K}^K\frac{1}{(x-k)^2}$$ and then show that the Weierstrass-M-test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test can be apllied to both sequences. Does anyone have any idea how to do this using the hint described above (so without Herglotz trick for example) and how to continue after showing that the M-test can be apllied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb Z$. Fix a natural number $K>|x|$. Then $x\in[-K,K]$. Then$$\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty\left|\frac1{(x-k)^2}\right|\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k-K)^2}<+\infty.$$The same thing holds for $\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty\frac1{(x+k)^2}$. So, your hint exrpesses $f(x)$ as the sum of $3$ functions, each of which is continuous at $x$.

Comment: Why are these functions continuous? Does that follow from the Weierstrass test?

Comment: @dirkpra Yes. The Weierstrass $M$-test implies that the convergence is uniform and the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: How do we know or how can we show that $f(x)$ is well-defined for $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @dirkpra Because, for each such $x$, both series converge (uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence).